# Solve equation containing sine and exponential function for x

Tags: analysis

leaving the context behind, I simplified a problem to the following equation:

solve for x: $$e^{\frac{-x}{a}} \cdot \sin(b + cx) = \sin(b)$$

Since my equations contains both sine and exponential function, I could neither use $\ln$ nor $\sin(x)^{-1}$. I tried using eulers identity to reduce all sine functions to exponential functions. Sadly, this couldn't help me either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you pick $c$ arbitrarily? It then has a solution for certain choice of it.

Comment: Well, c is given. Specified, c is an angular frequency $\omega = 2 \pi f$. There is a specific case in which $w = 2 \pi 83$, but it would be nice To have a General solution.

Comment: How about $b$ and $a$? Are these quantities related to $c$? I guess this matters for a general solution.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are not related to $c$. $a$ is a time-constant, $a \in \mathbb R_+$. $b \in [0, 2\pi)$ or $b \in [0°, 360°)$

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this into
$$
f(x) = e^{-x/a} \sin(b + cx) - \sin(a)
$$
and look for the roots.

$f$ seems to be a variation of a sine function modulated by an exponential function.

E.g.

[image]

Looks like a signal from electrical engineering.
Maybe they have a non-numerical solution?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late edit, the last part is $\sin(b)$.
Indeed, it is. The problem is the following. I want to know if a certain value $y_0$ or $y(x=0)$ returns in $y(x) = r \cdot e^{\frac{-x}{a}} \cdot \sin(b + cx)$. Writing this as a equation, I get the one from above.
I am able to get to a solution numerically, but it would be satisfying if there was a mathematical solution.